# Creation of a bibliography in Lyx

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, jabref

I use Lyx 2.1, document class : report.
I inserted the bibliography at the end of the document Lyx.
I created my. bib with JabRef: citation order is wrong:

if I add a new citation, it takes the number [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPYnd.png) and the former will be [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxFj4.png)
I want the new quote will be the last number + 1 (increment)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *How* did you insert it. There are several ways to make a bibliography: you may make it by hand, create a. bib file and use bibtex or biber, &c.

Comment: I inserted via the menu Lyx (I clicked on insert bibliography)

Comment: But do you have a .bib file? (I never used Lyx). Or do you have a `thebibliography` environment, with a number of `\bibitem` commands inside?

Comment: I just inserted the bibliography and I do not know what to do next

Comment: Can't you see the corresponding LaTeX code?

Comment: I've just seen how Lyx works. As I understand it, you've inserted a .bib file, and used JabRef to produce the .bib file, right? If this is the case, you just have to ask Lyx to produce the resulting file. What happens behind the scene is  launching LaTeX on the source-code, the BibTeX on the .bibfile, the again LaTeX (twice, to resolve the cross-references).

Comment: \bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{onehalfspace}

\end{document}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15182/discussion-between-bernard-and-goldray).

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you used insert bibliography you need a .bib file. I use zotero to create minw.

You can check the Lyx wiki for more information.

http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/BibTeX